# field collection value not worked with entity form when using conditional field

Tags: entities

I have created one *entity form* with *conditional field* and *field collection* in it but when I see the saved entity after submission, my values are not coming.

1) In first step user see the selection radio button with value A and B.

2) When A is selected, some files are visible some are not because I used conditional field in this.

3) Now when I fill the step 1 of *multi-step* form (Field collection in first step) and go to step 2 and fill the values and submit the form, the form values are visible in submission.

4) Now when I select the B and fill the form in first step using field collection and go to next step. After filling submit in submission step 1 of B selection is not coming only the value added in the second step of B are visible in submission.

How can I solve this as I have seen on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/) there is some issue in field collection with entity form. I tried many patches but no success.

My entity form structure is like this;

```
1) Multipagegroup

2)select A   ----   B with conditional field 

3)multipage1------------------------------------step 1 of form

   4)Text field------------------visible in step 1 when selected A only

   5)Field collection 1-----------visible in step 1 when selected A only 

   6)Field collection 2-----------visible in step 1 when selected B only 

7)multipage2------------------------------------step 2 of multi-step form

   8)Common text fields for both A and B for the second step--(common field)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a copy of [existing bugreport](https://www.drupal.org/node/1714272) and should be solved in issue queue, not here.

Comment: I didn't get any solution from that post no patch are worked for me that's why posted here that is different question.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's not *exactly* the same bug, but these modules are incompatible, and issues like this are offtopic - see Help Center. Decision not to do bugfixing here was made at the beginning of this site, because it's harmful to divide bugfixing efforts between two sites.